# Discord.js Embed Script Box

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know how to make a box in a description of an embed. For example -

When you use -

```js
<script>
```

It makes a script like box in your message.
Anyone know how you can do one of those in an embed

```js
channel.send({embed: {
    color: 3447003,
    author: {
    },
    title: "Example",
    description: ``,
    fields: [{
        name: "Example",
        value: `Example` <---- here
      }
    ],
    footer: {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add \` before and After the Text you want to use it on or use \`\`\` before and After if it is multiline (You can google for "discord markdown" for further information)